# Continuation of a number sequence

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

What numbers are next in this sequence and why?

> 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 10, 10, 9, 14, 9, 10, 14, 14, 15, 16, 18 ....

Hint:

> square numbers are involved

Hint 2:

> LCD display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it:

> the number of segments in a 7 segment LCD display that light up for $n^2$? 1 = 2,  4 = 4, 9 = 6, 16 = 8, 25 = 10, 36 = 11, etc...

Comment: congrats, that's it!